# Formulating the minimum distance between two points as an optimal control problem.

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

I came across this link that formulates the brachistochrone problem as an optimal control problem:
[brachistochrone](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/BrachistochroneProblem).
Instead of minimizing the time, I'd like - by using the same dynamics - to make the problem minimum distance between the two points A and B. So, in this case, is the following objective function correct?

$$ min\ J = \int_0^{t_f} v(t) dt\, $$
where $ t_f $ is free.

Comment: What is the control parameter, what are the constraints?

Comment: Wouldn't the shortest distance just be a straight line?

Comment: The control variable as in the link is $$ u=\theta$$ which is bounded $$(0, \pi/2)$$.